# how to initialize something of type 3 ints of a structure?

Tags: c, types, int, structure, typedef

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NAMESTRLEN 6
#define DETAILSTRLEN 40

typedef char namestr[NAMESTRLEN+1];
typedef char detailstr[DETAILSTRLEN+1];

typedef struct {
int d, m, y;
} date_t;

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
car_t Honda;
strcpy(Honda.rego_number, "12345");
strcpy( Honda.manufacturer, "thing");
strcpy( Honda.make, "thing");
strcpy( Honda.body, "thing");
strcpy( Honda.type, "thing");
strcpy( Honda.color, "thing");

//Here is the part i don't get://

Honda.first_registered=1,2,3;
Honda.current_registered=1,4,6;

Honda.number_owners= 10;

printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s    %d, %d.   %d\n", Honda.rego_number,Honda.manufacturer,
    Honda.make, Honda.body, Honda.type, Honda.color,Honda.first_registered,
    Honda.current_registered,Honda.number_owners);

return 0;
}
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: Where's the `Honda` structure ?

Comment: The updated post includes the definition of `Honda` but not the definition of its type, `car_t`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Honda.first_registered=1,2,3;
```

C doesn't allow you to assign individual fields of a struct in this manner.

You have several choices.  You can assign each field individually:

```
Honda.first_registered.d = 1;
Honda.first_registered.m = 2;
Honda.first_registered.y = 3;
```

You can create a temporary object of type `date_t` and *initialize* it using aggregate initialization syntax, and then assign it:

```
date_t registered_date = {1, 2, 3}; // note { and }
...
Honda.first_registered = registered_date; // assign a struct to a struct
```

As of C99, you can use a *compound literal*:

```
Honda.first_registered = (date_t) {1, 2, 3}; // note cast and { and }
```

which effectively does the same thing as the second method, except that you don't have to create a separate struct variable.

Comment: thanks! that really helped.but how come this does't work: Honda.first_registered= {1,2,3} if Hoda.first_registered is already of type date_t?

Comment: @Charlottekinsky: The short answer is that the language grammar doesn't allow it; there's no way for `{1,2,3}` to be a valid operand of the `=` operator without the cast.  *Why* the language was designed that way I'm not qualified to answer, but I suspect it's because `{1,2,3}`, by itself, is ambiguous; it could represent a struct of 3 int members, or a 3-element array of `int`, or some other aggregate type.

Answer (score -2):

Just as `number_owners` is a field of `Honda`, `d`, `m` and `y` are fields of `Honda.first_registered` and `Honda.current_registered`, so you would use the same technique to assign to them as you did to assign a 0 to `Honda.number_owners`.

Note that you will have to do something similar to print these registered fields out: break them down into their 3 components.